# Pandas extracting value from column in Dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a column in my Dataframe that has data in the below format

```
id,value
101,[{'self': 'https://www.web.com/rest/api/101', 'value': 'Yes', 'id': '546'}]
```

The type of the column (value) is of type `pandas.core.series.Series`.

I am trying to extract text corresponding to `value` in the above dataframe.

Expected output:

```
id, output
101,Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

See if his works for you

```
a=df['value'].str[0].apply(pd.Series)
df['value']=a['value']
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
     id     value
0   101     Yes
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cols = ['id', 'value']
data = [
  [101, [{'self': 'https://www.web.com/rest/api/101', 'value': 'Yes', 'id': '546'}]]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)

df.value = df.apply(lambda x: x['value'][0]['value'], axis=1)
print(df)
```

### Result

```
    id value
0  101   Yes
```